# Integration of $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} (\sin^6 2x+\cos^6 2x) \cdot\ln (1+\tan x) dx$

Tags: integration, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I've found an integration problem from Molodova Matholympiad 2008.
The problem is as follows.

Find the Integration of $$\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{4} (\sin^6 2x+\cos^6 2x) \cdot \ln (1+\tan x)\ \mathrm dx$$

My approach is as follows.
[image][image]

Can anyone help me to find the full solution?

Comment: I think you wrote $x = \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$ instead of $x = \frac{\pi}{4}-\theta$. Now use that $\ln \frac{2}{1 + \tan\theta} = \ln 2 - \ln (1 + \tan\theta)$. If $I$ is the integral, it gives $I = -I + \ln(2)\int_0^{\pi/4}(\cos^6 2\theta+\sin^6 2\theta) d t$. You can linearize this integral.

Comment: Moldova National MO 2008, 12 Grade, Problem 8 (Day 2). A solution is given here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h191848p1053472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ where $$g(x) = \sin^6 2x + \cos^6 2x, \quad h(x) = \log(1 + \tan x).$$  Then $$g(\pi/4 - x) = g(x), \\ h(\pi/4 - x) = \log\left(1 + \tan (\tfrac{\pi}{4} - x)\right) = \log \left( 1 + \frac{1 - \tan x}{1 + \tan x} \right) = \log \frac{2}{1 + \tan x} = \log 2 - h(x).$$  Consequently, $$f(\pi/4 - x) + f(x) = g(x) \log 2,$$ and we have
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} f(x) + f(\pi/4-x) \, dx = \frac{\log 2}{2} \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} g(x) \, dx.$$  Since
$$\begin{align}
a^6 + b^6 &= (a^2 + b^2)(a^4 - a^2 b^2 + b^4) \\
&= (a^2 + b^2)(a^4 + 2a^2 b^2 + b^4 - 3a^2 b^2) \\
&= (a^2 + b^2)\left((a^2 + b^2)^2 - 3a^2 b^2\right)
\end{align}$$
it follows that $$\begin{align}
g(x) &= 1 - 3 \sin^2 2x \cos^2 2x \\
&= 1 - \frac{3}{4} \sin^2 4x \\
&= 1 - \frac{3}{8} (1 - \cos 8x) \\
&= \frac{1}{8}(5 + 3 \cos 8x).
\end{align}$$

Putting everything together,
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} f(x) \, dx = \frac{\log 2}{16} \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} 5 + 3 \cos 8x \, dx = \frac{5\pi \log 2}{64}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

*This was done for the upper bound equal to $\frac \pi 2$ as written in the initial post.*

Tedious but doable using Feynman's trick.

Consider
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \left(\sin ^6(2 x)+\cos ^6(2 x)\right) \log (1+a \tan (x))\,dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{\tan (x) \left(\sin ^6(2 x)+\cos ^6(2 x)\right)}{1+a \tan (x)}\,dx$$ Now, using $x=\tan^{-1}(t)$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^9-8 t^7+30 t^5-8 t^3+t}{\left(1+t^2\right)^5\, (1+a t)}\,dt$$ Using partial fraction decomposition, only two types of integrals remain
$$J_n=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {dt}{(1+t^2)^n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (n)}$$
$$K_n=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {t}{(1+t^2)^n}\,dt=\frac{1}{2 (n-1)}$$
The final result is
$$16   \left(a^2+1\right)^5\,I'(a)=16 \left(a^8-10 a^6+10 a^2-1\right)+$$ $$\pi  a \left(5 a^8-4 a^6+198 a^4-148
   a^2+29\right)-$$ $$16 \left(a^8-8 a^6+30 a^4-8 a^2+1\right) \log (a)$$

Again, a bunch of partial fraction decomposition and integration between $0$ and $1$ lead to
$$\int_0^1 \frac{a^8-10 a^6+10 a^2-1}{\left(a^2+1\right)^5}\,dt=0$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\pi  a \left(5 a^8-4 a^6+198 a^4-148 a^2+29\right)}{16
   \left(a^2+1\right)^5}\,dt=\frac{5}{32} \pi  \log (2)$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{a^8-8 a^6+30 a^4-8 a^2+1 }{\left(a^2+1\right)^5} \log (a)\,dt=-\frac{5 C}{8}-\frac{1}{16}$$

$$\color{blue}{\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \left(\sin ^6(2 x)+\cos ^6(2 x)\right) \log (1+ \tan (x))\,dx=\frac{5 }{8}C+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{5}{32} \pi  \log (2)}$$

**Edit**

Changing the bound
$$I'(a)=\int_0^{1} \frac{t^9-8 t^7+30 t^5-8 t^3+t}{\left(1+t^2\right)^5\, (1+a t)}\,dt$$ the same process does repeat and
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \left(\sin ^6(2 x)+\cos ^6(2 x)\right) \log (1+ \tan (x))\,dx=\frac{5}{64} \pi  \log (2)}$$

Comment: While this is impressive, the upper limit of integration is $\pi/4$, not $\pi/2$.

Comment: @heropup. I just noticed but the $\pi/2$ was in the initial post (remember, if you know it, that I am blind). Cheers :-)

Comment: @heropup. We can use the same process (edited).

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I'm really sorry for writing $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ . But Thanks a lot for doing such a huge work.

Comment: @SaadJunior. Please, don't worry   ! The problem  was interesting. Cheers :-)