# How to deal with odd $m$ in integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\sin^{6}m x+\cos^{6}m x) \ln (1+\tan x) d x $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry

***Latest edit***

1. Thanks to @Quanto for settling down the question by proving the odd one as:$$I_{2n+1}= \frac{5\pi}{64}\ln2+\frac3{16(2n+1)}\bigg(\frac\pi4-\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1} \bigg)$$
   By our results for **both** odd and even multiples $n$ of $x$, we can conclude that

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin ^{6}(nx)+\cos ^{6}(nx)\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x =\frac{5 \pi\ln 2}{64}
$$

2. As asked by @Claude Leibovici for the powers other than 6, I had generalised my result to even powers below as an answer:
   $$
   I(m,n):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\cos ^{2 m}(2 nx)+\sin ^{2 m}(2 n x)\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x= \frac{\pi \ln 2}{4} \cdot \frac{(2 m-1) ! !}{(2 m) ! !}
   $$

---

In order to evaluate the even case

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin^{6}(2 n x)+\cos^{6}(2 nx)\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x $$
we first simplify
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\sin ^{6}(2 n x)+\cos ^{6}(2 n x) =& {\left[\sin ^{2}(2 n x)+\cos ^{2}(2 n x)\right]\left[\sin ^{4}(2 n x)-\sin ^{2}(2 n x) \cos ^{2}(2 n x)\right) } \\&\left.+\cos ^{4}(2 n x)\right] \\=& 1-3 \sin ^{2}(2 n x) \cos ^{2}(2 n x) \\=& 1-\frac{3}{4} \sin ^{2}(4 n x) \\=& 1-\frac{3}{8}(1-\cos 8 n x) \\=& \frac{1}{8}(5+3 \cos (8nx))\end{aligned} \tag*{} $

To get rid of the natural logarithm, a simple substitution transforms the integral into

$\begin{aligned}I &=\frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(5+3 \cos (8 n x)) \ln (1+\tan x) d x \\& \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{4}-x}{=} \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(5+3 \cos (8 n x)) \ln \left(1+\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\right) d x \\&=\frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(5+3 \cos (8 n x)) \ln \left(\frac{2}{1+\tan x}\right) d x \\&=\frac{1}{8} \ln 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(5+3 \cos (8 n x) )d x-I \\I &=\frac{\ln 2}{16} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(5+3 \cos 8  n x) d x\\&=\frac{\ln 2}{16}\left[5 x+\frac{3}{8 n} \sin (8 n x)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{4} }\\ &=\frac{5 \pi}{64} \ln 2\end{aligned} \tag*{} $

***My Question:***

How can we deal with the odd one
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin ^{6}(2 n +1)x+\cos ^{6}(2 n +1)x\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x  ?$$

Can you help?

Comment: Dear friend, all definite integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is constant. Have I misunderstood your question maybe?

Comment: @Piquito. It means independent of $n$

Comment: Good job ! For the last question, it is not a constant but it *seems* to tend to the same value

Comment: Sir, you are right. They are not a constant but very close.

Comment: @Lai A question is to find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin ^{6}(2 n +1)x+\cos ^{6}(2 n +1)x\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x$.

Comment: I am just thinking the same question.

Comment: You can solve this integral by using the identity $\int_{a}^bf(x)=\int_a^bf(a+b-x
) d x$

Comment: @Lai The limit is $(5/64)\pi \ln 2$ which is also equal to $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin ^{6}(2 n x)+\cos ^{6}(2 n x)\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x$ ($n\ge 1$).

Comment: I agree with you.  I shall give the solution later.

Comment: The existence of the limit is guaranteed by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Comment: @RiverLi. I wrote the asymptotics. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Sorry, you just give the result but do not give the reasoning. It is not easy to verify it e.g. by hand. For example, I used computer to get $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x^3 (\pi-x)^3}{\sin^3 x}\, dx=126\pi^2 \zeta (3) -\left(1395+\frac{279\pi^2}{2}\right)\zeta(5) +\frac{5715}{4}\zeta(7)$, however it is far from an answer, we need to give the reasoning, not just give the result.

Comment: @RiverLi. Are you sure that your comment is related to this question ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, just like my example, you used computer (right?) to give the asymptotics. I think we need the process how to obtain it (e.g. by hand) or it is easy to verify it by hand.

Comment: @RiverLi  I used what I wrote in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436446/integration-of-int-0-frac-pi4-sin6-2x-cos6-2x-cdot-ln-1-tan-x-d/4436501#4436501 before the edit. By the way, I "saw" (I am blind) the problem of $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x^3 (\pi-x)^3}{\sin^3 x}\, dx$ but I don't find it again. Could you give me the link ? Thanks & cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think you should including the necessary details rather than just giving the result. That problem is in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437032/tough-integral-int-0-pi-fracx2-pi-x2-sin2-x-dx-6-pi-zeta3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to the even case, recognize
$$\sin ^{6}mx+\cos ^{6}mx = \frac58+\frac38 \cos4mx $$ and rewrite the integral as follows
\begin{align}
I_{2n+1}=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin ^{6}(2 n +1)x+\cos ^{6}(2 n +1)x\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x  \\
=&\> \frac58\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln \overset{\frac\pi4-x \to x}{(1+\tan x) } d x 
+ \frac38\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}
\cos4(2n+1)x\ln\frac{\sqrt2\cos(\overset{\frac\pi4-x \to x}{\frac\pi4-x})}{\cos x}dx\\
=&\> \frac58\cdot \frac\pi8\ln2- 
\frac34\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}
\cos4(2n+1)x\ln \cos x\> \overset{ibp}{dx}\\
=&\> \frac{5\pi}{64}\ln2-\frac3{16(2n+1)}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin 4(2n+1)x\sin x}{\cos x}dx\tag1
\end{align}
Derive the integral below recursively
\begin{align}
K_m=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin 4m x\sin x}{\cos x}dx
= K_{m-1}+\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2m-1}=-\frac\pi4+\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}\\
\end{align}
Then, evaluate $K_{2n+1}$ and plug into (1) to obtain
$$I_{2n+1}= \frac{5\pi}{64}\ln2+\frac3{16(2n+1)}\bigg(\frac\pi4-\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1} \bigg)
$$
In contrast, the even case $I_{2n}= \frac{5\pi}{64}\ln2$ is much simpler.

Comment: Very nice answer.  Now, a question : what is the role of $6$ in this story ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I guess 6 is high enough to make the integral interesting, but not too high to be unmanageable

Comment: Let me work with other powers. Thanks & cheers

Comment: I had done for even power and even multiple is x as another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Quanto for settling down the question by proving the odd one as:$$I_{2n+1}= \frac{5\pi}{64}\ln2+\frac3{16(2n+1)}\bigg(\frac\pi4-\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1} \bigg)
$$
As asked by @Claude Leibovici for the powers other than 6, I had generalised my result to even powers below:
$$
I(m,n):=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\cos ^{2 m}(2 nx)+\sin ^{2 m}(2 n x)\right] \ln (1+\tan x) d x= \frac{\pi \ln 2}{4} \cdot \frac{(2 m-1) ! !}{(2 m) ! !}
$$
Proof:
Letting $x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{4}-x $ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, n) &=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin ^{2 m}(2 x)+\cos ^{2 m}(2 x)\right) \ln \left(\frac{2}{1+\tan x}\right]d x \\
&=\ln 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin^{2m} (2 n x)+\cos ^{2 m}(2 n x) \right] d x-I(m, n)\\ I(m, n)&= \frac{\ln 2}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left[\sin^{2m} (2n x)+\cos ^{2 m}(2nx)\right]d x\\& = \frac{\ln 2}{4} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[\sin^{2m} (n x)+\cos ^{2 m}(nx)\right]d x\\&\stackrel{nx\mapsto x}  {=}\frac{\ln 2}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{n \pi}{2}} \sin ^{2 m} x d x\\&= \frac{\ln 2}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2 m} x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Using Wallis Formula, we can conclude that $$
\boxed{I(m, n)=\frac{\pi \ln 2}{4} \cdot \frac{(2 m-1) ! !}{(2 m) ! !}},
$$
which is ***independent*** of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Quanto provided a detailed and very good answer, I shall make the story short.

Working directly the problem of the difference between two consecutive terms
$$I_{2n+1}-I_{2n}=-\frac{3 }{32 } \frac{1 }{2 n+1}\Phi \left(-1,1,\frac{4n+3}{2}\right)$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function.

We can also write it as
$$I_{2n+1}-I_{2n}=-\frac{3 }{64 }\frac{1 }{2 n+1} \left(H_{n+\frac{1}{4}}-H_{n-\frac{1}{4}}\right)$$ These are very small numbers. Expanded as series
$$I_{2n+1}-I_{2n}=-\frac{3}{256 n^2}\Bigg[1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{11}{16 n^2}-\frac{3}{8 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \Bigg]$$